# C# ref weird behaviour

Tags: c#, object, reference, parameter-passing, ref

I recently had a strange experience with C# refs.

Please take a look at this code:

```
class Program
{
    public static bool testBool = true;
    public static RefClass RefObject;
    public static int X = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            
            if (testBool)
            {
                RefObject = new RefClass(ref X);
                testBool = false;
            }

            X++;
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Debug.WriteLine(X);
            Debug.WriteLine(RefObject.X);
        }
    }

    public class RefClass
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public RefClass(ref int x)
        {
            X = x;
        }
    }
}
```

I still can't figure out why the property `X` of `RefObject` doesn't update with the variable `X`. Isn't `ref` supposed to be a reference to the original variable? That would mean that `X` (property of `RefObject`) should be only a reference to the static `X` variable, which is supposed to result it them being the same.

Comment: The idea is that if you assigned a new value to `x` in the constructor of `RefClass`, you could observe it, but you didn't. New assignments after the fact are not involved, and RefClass.X is not forever linked to your initial argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the constructor:

```
public RefClass(ref int x)
{
    X = x;
}
```

Specifically this line:

```
X = x;
```

At this point, the lower-case `x` variable **IS** a `ref` variable. However, when you copy it to the upper-case `X` property, you are still copying it's **value** at that time to the property. The `X` property is still just a regular integer, and as far as I know there is no way to declare a reference property in the way you want.

Comment: It is impossible because it would make RefClass hold a reference to something defined outside it's scope, literally meaning.... that you would... create a ton of problems with isolation down the road. Note how all uses of ref flow along a code path - having a ref variable would mean that the reference would exist outside of the code path.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious about the explenation! Thanks againg and have a nice day!